# ElasticSearch Chaining queries based on result from first query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some data and I am looking to implement a search feature that probably requires chaining multiple queries. for example there are few people who are part of a group but each member in the database are separate. None of the data is nested.

For example

```
data = [
{
id: '1'
name: 'abc',
familyId: '3'
},
{
id: '2'
name: 'def',
familyId: '3'
},
{
id: '3'
name: 'ghi',
familyId: null
},

]
```

So now I am trying to implement a search feature where people can search by name, and if the name matches I want to show that result along with his family members. Each data is different and there is no connection between them apart from the familyId.

So currently my solution is to make a search using the name first and then from the result of my first search I will see if there is family ID present in the result, and if yes make another ES query to get all the members and then show the result.

Is there a away I could make it one query that will give me the desired output?

Any suggestion is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

there's no native Elasticsearch functionality for this unfortunately, your approach is the current best way to do it